# Yodlee Simulate MFA

Tags: yodlee

We are at the end of our integration and we are trying to test the MFA workflow with yodlee.

How can we simulate that some accounts need to be refreshed and that these refresh required an MFA of type Captcha, Token and Q&A ?

I am using the Dummy account generator https://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/lndhaction.do but I don't have the answers for Q&A and Token MFA account.

Moreover, the captcha MFA account, how can I simulate the MFA is required on every refresh ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Dummy Account Generator and the answers for Q/A & Token MFA are present in the XMLs.
For e.g., if you are using Site based DAG then you can click on download link present next to the password value for that DAG, in case of DAG Site- Security Q/A  then next to "site16486.2". Similarly for Token as well.
While for CAPTCHA, there is a CAPTCHA image attached to the CAPTCHA DAG which will be returned as a string(image converted into base64). You need to convert that base64 string into image and enter the CAPTCHA in the response.

So, Yodlee don't refresh as a daily refresh process the sites which has CAPTCHA/Token MFA. You need to call startSiteRefresh or startRefresh7(if using container based).